# nearPoints gets confused by .data: xvar not in names of input

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity

The following code does not work:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(shiny)
shinyApp(ui=fluidPage(
            plotOutput("plot", click="clicked"),
            tableOutput("near")),
         server=function(input, output, session) {
           df <- data.frame(x=rnorm(100), y=rnorm(100))
           output$plot <- renderPlot({
             ggplot(df, aes(x=.data$x, y=.data$y)) + geom_point()
           })

           output$near <- renderTable({
             nearPoints(df, input$clicked)
           })    
         })
```

When a point on the plot is clicked, following error appears:

```
nearPoints: `xvar` ('.data$x')  not in names of input
```

If instead the ggplot statement above, the following statement is used

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y)) + geom_point()
```

everything works as expected.

The reason why I am using `data$x` (or `data[["x"]]`, which also gives an error) in `aes()` is that this code is inside of a package, and `data[["x"]]` was used to eliminate R package check warnings (as described in [programming with dplyr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/programming.html)). I could circumvent the problem in the plotting function rather than in the shiny app I am working on (e.g. by defining dummy variables x and y), but first, this is not elegant, and second, what if one day I have a plotting function from another package which uses a similar trick?

My question: how to make the above code work in shiny *without* modifying the ggplot statement?

Comment: Can't you use `aes_string(x = "x", y = "y")`? Otherwise you can also specify `xvar` and `yvar` in `nearPoints`, that is `nearPoints(df, input$clicked, xvar="x", yvar="y")`.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent ah, that's it! The latter solution, I mean. Thank you! Please submit as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify `xvar` and `yvar` in the `nearPoints` function, that is

```
nearPoints(df, input$clicked, xvar="x", yvar="y")
```